# Updating has_one :though with a has_many-style join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following models

```rb
class Widget
  has_one :widget_sprocket
  has_one :sprocket, through: :widget_sprockets
end

class Sprocket
  has_many :widget_sprockets
  has_many :widgets, though: :widget_sprockets
end

class WidgetSprocket
  belongs_to :widget
  belongs_to :sprocket
end
```

This works fine in the console, but I'm struggling with view updates for Widget. `has_many :through` gives Sprocket `widget_ids`, which I believe can be treated like a local attribute for most purposes, but the [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) evidently expect a different table configuration for `has_one :through` and therefore doesn't define a `sprocket_id` on Widget. As a result code like this throws an `unknown attribute` error

```rb
<%= f.collection_select(:sprocket_id, Sprocket.all, :id, :sprocket_type)  %>
```

Of course I could use `has_many :through` for both models, but I consider it a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're falling for a classic trap and overcomplicating this. If you want a one to many assocation between Sprocket and Widget you should just be using `belongs_to` and adding a `sprocket_id` foreign key column to the `widgets` table:

```
class AddSprocketToWidgets < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :widgets, :sprocket, null: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

```
class Widget
  belongs_to :sprocket
end
```

This guarentees on the database level that a Widget can only have one Sprocket because the column can only hold one single value. Your join table gives no such guarentee. You're really just selecting the first matching row off the join table and its actually a many to many relation. Unless thats acceptable or you prevent it with unique indexes thats an invitation for some nasty bugs.

While there are scenarios where you actually need an intermediadary table that describes a one to many relation - YAGNI.

> has_many :through gives Sprocket widget_ids, which I believe can be treated like a local attribute for most purposes

Its not an attribute in any way or form. Its a method which will actually do a `SELECT id FROM other_table`query unless the assocation is preloaded.

> but the Rails docs evidently expect a different table configuration for has_one :through and therefore doesn't define a sprocket_id on Widget.

Classic noob trap caused by the confusing semantics of the method names. `has_one` means there is a foreign key column *on the other models table*. Its like `has_many` but with a `LIMIT 1` tacked onto the end of the query. To get the id you would actually call `other.id`.

In the case of `belongs_to` its not the relations macro that creates the attribute. Its having an actual `sprocket_id` column on the `widgets` table.

If you actually wanted to go though creating an intermediary table you  can't just assign an id. You would have to use nested attributes and fields_for to create or update a WidgetSprocket instance. Again YAGNI.

Comment: Hi Max. I did find your [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039617/965613) to a similar question, but for reasons I won't get into, I'm confident that my situation is different and that the relations I described are the ones I need. What I take from your answer is that I should either use many-to-many on both models or nested attributes / `fields_for` (which I did try to implement for this, but may have done incorrectly).